# environment variable not working in Google Code Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in google code colab by following statements:

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/path/to/library/used/by/my/software'
```

I can see the environment variable added in the environment variables list, checked by (!printenv), but when my exe tries to access the library stored at LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it is not able to find it.

```
NotFoundError: library_name.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried configuring the environment variables through colab-env package (https://pypi.org/project/colab-env/), but I am facing same issue with this approach also.

Can someone give pointers? Thank you.

Comment: How are you running your code to generate this error?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting up only in your notebook environment.

To configure in linux environment, you can use this:

```
!export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=<PATH HERE>
```

But I usually do this:

```
import os
!export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=<PATH HERE>
os.environ['AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE'] = <PATH HERE>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Claudio. I added export statement also, the main exe is still not able to find the .so library.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution with Colab is to first copy the executable file to Drive :

```
!cp /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/<FILE> /usr/local/bin.
```

Then allow to execute it:

```
!chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/<FILE>.
```

Courtesy of [Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/google-colab-59ad8510eb7e).